# iPhone Core Data: How to copy NSSet from one entity to another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

This code is used to make "initial data" or "test data".

The `Category` entity will carry default `types`.
The `Subcategory` entity will copy default `types` from the `Category`.
They wouldn't be using the same `types` because new or old `types` may be deleted or added to the `Subcategory`.

```
    -(void)newCat:(NSString*)catName subCat:(NSArray*)subCatNames types:(NSArray*)typeNames{
 //get the context
 NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

 //make a category
 Category *theCat = [NSEntityDescription
      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Category" 
      inManagedObjectContext:context];
 theCat.name = catName;

 //make default types and put it in the category
 for (int i = 0; i < [typeNames count]; i++) {
  Type *type = [NSEntityDescription
       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Type" 
       inManagedObjectContext:context];
  type.name = [typeNames objectAtIndex:i];
  [theCat addTypesObject:type];
 }

 //make some subcategories
 //copy default types from category to subcategory
 for (int i = 0; i < [subCatNames count]; i++) {
  Subcategory *newSubcat = [NSEntityDescription
       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Subcategory" 
       inManagedObjectContext:context];

  newSubcat.name = [logbookNames objectAtIndex:i];
  newSubcat.category = theCat;
  [newSubcat addTypes:theCat.types];
 }

 //save the context
 [self save];

 }
```

This method works the first time I open the app. Once I terminate and reopen the app, all but one `Subcategory` entity retains the `types`.

Why is the other `Subcategory` removing their `types`? I fear that I'm only setting a pointer to the default `types` in the `Category`.

How do I make a copy `Category.types` and set it as the types in `Subcategory.types`?

Design wise, should I create a new entity to hold default types for the Category instead of using the same entity for defaults and non-defaults?

Comment: well i found a fix, i don't know if this is the proper way to do it but I enumerated the default types.

Answer (score 0):

You types is a standard object, which u can receive and make [types copy]
after that u can do what u want with it.